# How to call ajax to retrieve data from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have build a laravel application.Where I want to search the data using date range. Here i'm using controller and after calling the controller,data get retrieved and redirecting to same page. Here there is situation like page load. But I don't want to load the whole page.instead of it, if I want to use ajax  to call the controller only that particular controller will be called and there is no redirection. How do I do it using Ajax?

Here is my controller:

```
public function reportByDate(Request $request)
{
     $revenue = DB::table('fees')
        ->join('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'fees.course_id')
        ->join('users', 'courses.id', '=', 'users.course_id')            
        ->where('users.completed_status', '=', 1)
        ->sum('fee');

        $startDate = $request->Input(['sdate']);
        $finshDate=$request->Input(['edate']);


     $input = DB::table('fees')->join('courses', 'fees.course_id', '=','courses.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
        ->where('users.completed_status', 1)
        ->whereBetween('users.date', [$startDate, $finshDate])
        ->groupBy('fees.course_id')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(fee) as fee, courses.name')
        ->get();


     return view('revenueDetails',['revenue'=>$revenue],['input'=>$input]);
}
```

Here is the view page:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
Revenue Details
@endsection
@section('content')

<div class="container">
<h3> Revenue Details </h3>
</br>
</br>

  {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'reportByDate','class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST'))  !!}
  {!! Form::token(); !!}
  {!!   csrf_field() ; !!} 
          <div class="form-group">
              <label> Start Date</label>  
              <input type="date" name="sdate" class="form-control" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label> End Date</label>  
              <input type="date" name="edate" class="form-control" >
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    {!! Form::close() !!}



<h4>Total Revenue: {{$revenue}}</h4></br>
</br>

      <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Serial No</td>
            <td>Course Name</td>            
            <td>Course Revenue</td>                      
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      {{--    {{dd($input)}} --}}
          <?php $i=1; ?>
         @foreach($input as $row)

          <tr>
            <td>{{$i}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->fee}}</td>



          </tr>
            <?php $i++; ?>     
        @endforeach


        </tbody>


      </table>
        <li><a href="{{ route('userDetails') }}">See the User Details</a></li>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json() helper to return data from your controller instead of loading a view:

in your controller:

```
return response()->json([
    'revenue' => $revenue,
    'input'   => $input
], 200);
```

Example of what the ajax call would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path/to/resource",
    data: { sdate: "foo", edate: "bar", token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(data) {

   // do something like diplay data;

}).fail(function(jqXHR, responseText) {

   // something went wrong
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return json response and rendering your html in ajax-callback function.
It's simple to do with laravel. Instead of  this string "return view('revenueDetails',['revenue'=>$revenue],['input'=>$input]);"
use this  "return response()->json(['revenue'=>$revenue,'input'=>$input]);"

You can read how to do ajax-request here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/